# Create AS3 countdown clock without using users system Clock

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, countdown

I need to create an as3 countdown clock for a TV display with no system clock.

How can I utilize the Date object for this?

Here is my code so far:

```
var targetDate:Date = new Date(2015, 6, 5, 19, 00, 00);
var dateStr:Date = new Date(2015, 5, 25, 18, 56, 00);


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(e:Event):void{

var nowDate:Date = new Date(dateStr);
var ms:Number = targetDate.getTime() - nowDate.getTime();
var sec:Number = Math.floor(ms/1000);
var min:Number = Math.floor(sec/60);
var hr:Number = Math.floor(min/60);
var day:Number = Math.floor(hr/24);




sec = sec % 60;
min = min % 60;
hr = hr % 24;

daytxt.text = day.toString();
hrtxt.text = (hr < 10) ? "0"+hr.toString() : hr.toString();
mintxt.text = (min < 10) ? "0"+min.toString() : min.toString();
sectxt.text = (sec < 10) ? "0"+sec.toString() : sec.toString();
//sec--;
trace(dateStr);
}
```

I'm trying to pass in the date parameters to the Date() constructor, but I cannot get it to count down.

Comment: I recommend you show your research. What did you do so far? What do you know so far?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using enterframe it's better to use Timer. You should set it for a 1000 millisecond ie one second . Here is a good tutorial for  [creating a timer.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/countdown-in-style-with-an-airport-terminal-timer--active-4056)